# iPhone: Show clean Camera feed without any on-screen controls

Tags: iphone, camera

Is there a way to show a **clean** feed of the Camera on iPhone screen? For example, if I go to the Camera app, I can see the record button, as well as the other controls and options.

I want to see nothing but what the Camera is seeing on the screen of my iPhone. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with the built-in Camera app, or with any other built-in app.

The built-in Camera app doesn't provide options to completely hide the top toolbar and the controls shown at the bottom.

Since this is technically feasible, you may search the App Store for any 3rd-party app(s) which offers the said functionality. For e.g., try searching for *minimalistic Camera app* on Web/App Store to look for relevant matches.

Answer (score 6):

After testing and searching paid and free apps for hours. I found a free app that does this, [True Visage](http://happymagenta.com/truevisage/). Tested with iPhone 8, connected to my MacBook with USB-C cable and recording into Quicktime. It has a minimal interface that disappears after a few secs. Leaving beautiful, HQ, controls-free, watermark-free views of front or rear camera. Also has a handy flip function. Winner!

This allows me to use my iphone like an external web camera, connected via USB-C, which looks much better than the icam native to my MacBook Pro.

Note: Notifications from other apps may still come on screen and show in the view. Disable notifications before going live.

Comment: @orrymr: If this works for you, please consider accepting this answer.

Comment: App is called "True Visage" couldn't find it cause there was a space

Comment: True Visage works amazingly well. It is EXACTLY what I needed, combined with OBS on Mac, I get a perfectly clean, high quality feed of my iPhone 7 Plus's main camera. Hard to believe this app is free!

Answer (score 4):

I was having this same issue and didn't find any free, easy solutions so I just created my own:

https://github.com/alexfromapex/camera-viewer

Comment: This is the simplest and cleanest solution. Just go to https://alexfromapex.github.io/camera-viewer/

Answer (score 3):

There's a newer app called Camra that works better than the other options listed here. The HTML `camera-viewer` does not allow camera zoom. True Visage still has some controls, and they take time to disappear.

Camra by contrast only shows controls when taking a photo, and they don't stay up for long. It's perfect if one wants to share an iPhone's video feed using Zoom's built-in feature to broadcast the phone's screen over a cable.

Comment: Where is documentation for this?  E.g. how does one set video resolution or frame rate?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is my paid iOS app that does exactly that, it's called [Clean Camera Feed](https://apps.apple.com/app/clean-camera/id1508874265).  I'm the creator of this app.

I stream with OBS and found that using other apps available caused a bunch of latency issues and trying to use multiple devices would slow down OBS etc. So decided to write and publish my own app as a solution.

It displays a fullscreen camera view and you can use touch gestures to control the screen (tap to focus, double tap to switch cameras, pinch to zoom, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Found an App that does exactly that. It's called Touch Camera.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find the software and evaluate it themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review